# What's the Python2.5 equivalent of Python2.6 translate with None as first param?

Tags: python

In Python 2.6, I can run the following fine to strip out chars like `-()`

```
'(123) 456-7890'.translate(None, '-(), ')
```

Python2.5 translate does not accept None, how can I do the above in 2.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be possible with `maketrans`:

```
import string
'(123) 456-7890'.translate(string.maketrans('', ''), '-(), ')
```

But you can also use regular expressions which is more readable.

Comment: Good answer, more to the spirit of the question!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`string.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) with empty arguments to create the *identity translation table*:

> `string.maketrans(from, to)`
>
> Return a translation table suitable for passing to translate(), that will map each character in from into the character at the same position in to; from and to must have the same length.

```
>>> import string
>>> identity = string.maketrans("", "")
>>> '(123) 456-7890'.translate(identity, '-(), ')
'1234567890'
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can always keep only the digits:

```
def strip_nondigits(text):
    return filter(type(text).isdigit, text)

>>> strip_nondigits('(123) 456-7890')
'1234567890'
```

This should be more robust against spurious characters. The `type(text)` makes it work for unicode objects too.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\-|\(|\)| ','','(123) 456-7890')
1234567890
```